# Install the package in the terminal by shell_exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, exec, shell-exec

I need to install a package from github in the php exec shell function. But in the installation phase, it asks me for 4 answers.
username
password
port
y/n
I want to enter the answers in order in the continuation of the installation with shell exec. But I don't know how.

Does not work :

[image]

```
<?php

 $cmd = 'bash <(curl -Ls https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mhsanaei/3x-ui/master/install.sh) -y -admin -admin -2053';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```